# NavigationLink Text blurry swiftui

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a section that I have some items inside and I want those items to trigger separate Views the problem I have is the color contrast on my NavigationLink Button is blurry but if I use a regular button, it come out correct. This is my code and this is the image that shows up

```
VStack {
    Form {
        Section {
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                HStack(spacing: 2) {
                    Image("logouticon")
                        .frame(height: 40)
                        .frame(width: 40)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    Text("Logout")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                        
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                    
                }.background(Color.clear)
            })
            NavigationLink(
                destination: EmptyView(),
                label: {
                    HStack(spacing: 2) {
                        Image("logouticon")
                            .frame(height: 40)
                            .frame(width: 40)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        Text("Logout")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                            
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                        
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The image below is the NavigationLink while the one above it is the Button

[image]

Comment: Can you make a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put all `NavigationLinks` in a `NavigationView` like this:

```
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Button(action: {}, label: {
                        HStack(spacing: 2) {
                            Image("logouticon")
                                .frame(height: 40)
                                .frame(width: 40)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                            Text("Logout")
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                                .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                
                                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                .foregroundColor(.black)
                            
                        }.background(Color.clear)
                    })
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: EmptyView(),
                        label: {
                            HStack(spacing: 2) {
                                Image("logouticon")
                                    .frame(height: 40)
                                    .frame(width: 40)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                Text("Logout")
                                    .foregroundColor(.red)
                                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .regular, design: .default))
                                    
                                    .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                                
                            }
                        }
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Otherwise, they are dimmed because they are disabled.